# PHP/MySQL insert row then get 'id'

Tags: php, mysql

The 'id' field of my table auto increases when I insert a row. I want to insert a row and then get that ID.

I would do it just as I said it, but is there a way I can do it without worrying about the time between inserting the row and getting the id?

I know I can query the database for the row that matches the information that was entered, but there is a high change there will be duplicates, with the only difference being the id.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'my_user', 'my_pass', 'my_db');
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO mytable (1, 2, 3, 'blah')");
$id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

See [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://au.php.net/mysqli.insert_id).

Whatever you do, don't insert and then do a "`SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable`". Like you say, it's a race condition and there's no need. `mysqli_insert_id()` already has this functionality.

---

Another way would be to run both queries in one go, and using `MySQL`'s `LAST_INSERT_ID()` method, where both tables get modified at once (and PHP does not need any ID), like:

```php
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO my_user_table ...;
  INSERT INTO my_other_table (`user_id`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID())");
```

> **Note** that Each connection keeps track of ID separately (so, conflicts are prevented already).

Comment: The PDO equivalent is PDO::lastInsertId (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Comment: the link leads me to the russian version of mysql_insert_id @php.net :P

Comment: Does it still works if there will 10000 async inserts at the same time?

Comment: @zie1ony Yes, it would work for a million async inserts because MySQL is ACID compliant. Each individual insert from the many async inserts is within its own *isolated* session, which is where the ID comes from when you call mysql_insert_id() from your PHP (or LAST_INSERT_ID() in MySQL)

Comment: On the doc there is something to note: `mysql_insert_id() will convert the return type of the native MySQL C API function mysql_insert_id() to a type of long (named int in PHP). If your AUTO_INCREMENT column has a column type of BIGINT (64 bits) the conversion may result in an incorrect value. Instead, use the internal MySQL SQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() in an SQL query. For more information about PHP's maximum integer values, please see the integer documentation.`\

Comment: need to rewrite everything i've ever written -_-

Comment: From http://php.net/mysql_insert_id : "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."

Comment: @smcjones I think what's worth mentioning, is that the code above is actually incorrect since both functions used here requires `mysqli $link` (returned by `mysqli_connect` or `mysqli_init`) as first argument.

Comment: Thanks - you're right. I usually use object oriented style, not procedural.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira: Each insert is ACID even without using transactions?

Comment: Yes, each insert is ACID. The transaction would allow you to undo (rollback) a series of inserts, deletes, updates, etc. all in one _atomic_ shot, however.

Answer (score 40):

The MySQL function [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) does just what you need: it retrieves the id that was inserted during *this session*. So it is safe to use, even if there are other processes (other people calling the exact same script, for example) inserting values into the same table.

The PHP function [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) does the same as calling `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` with `mysql_query()`.

Comment: NB  
`echo mysql_insert_id();  
mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(600)');  
echo mysql_insert_id();  
mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');  `
  
The second `mysql_insert_id()` doesn't reflect 600, where as `mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()')` will.
To get the `mysql_insert_id()` to reflect the change you have to first do an insert or an update (which can affect 0 rows).

See very last paragraph of:[http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Answer (score 31):

As to PHP's website, mysql_insert_id is now deprecated and we must use either [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (See [@Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425584/1046013) for MySQLi). To do this with PDO, proceed as following:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO people(name, city) VALUES(:name, :city)');
$statement->execute([':name' => 'Bob', ':city' => 'Montreal']);

echo $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: We have the option to use either PDO *or* MySQLi (which I describe in another answer here). A good comparison: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Answer (score 23):

As @NaturalBornCamper said, [mysql_insert_id is now deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) and should *not* be used. The options are now to use  either PDO or mysqli. NaturalBornCamper explained PDO in his answer, so I'll show how to do it with **MySQLi** ([MySQL Improved](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)) using [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

```
// First, connect to your database with the usual info...
$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
// Let's assume we have a table called 'people' which has a column
// called 'people_id' which is the PK and is auto-incremented...
$db->query("INSERT INTO people (people_name) VALUES ('Mr. X')");
// We've now entered in a new row, which has automatically been 
// given a new people_id. We can get it simply with:
$lastInsertedPeopleId = $db->insert_id;
// OR
$lastInsertedPeopleId = mysqli_insert_id($db);
```

Check out the PHP documentation for more examples: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I really prefer Javascript's dot notation over PHP's arrow notation. :/

Answer (score 7):

I just want to add a small detail concerning `lastInsertId()`;

**When entering more than one row at the time, it does not return the last Id**, but the first Id of the collection of last inserts.

Consider the following example

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO my_table (varNumb,userid) VALUES
     (1, :userid),
     (2, :userid)';
$sql->addNewNames = $db->prepare($sql);
addNewNames->execute(array(':userid' => $userid));

echo $db->lastInsertId();
```

What happens here is that I push in `my_table` two new rows. The id of the table is auto-increment. Here, for the same user, I add two rows with a different `varNumb`.

The echoed value at the end will be equal to the id of the row where `varNumb=1`, which means not the id of the *last* row, but the id of the first row that was added in the last request.

Comment: stick to one operation at a time - seems to be the overall answer for all methods used, to avoid unexpected behaviours

Answer (score 1):

An example.

```
    $query_new = "INSERT INTO students(courseid, coursename) VALUES ('', ?)";
    $query_new = $databaseConnection->prepare($query_new);
    $query_new->bind_param('s', $_POST['coursename']);
    $query_new->execute();
    $course_id = $query_new->insert_id;
    $query_new->close();
```

The code line `$course_id = $query_new->insert_id;` will display the ID of the last inserted row. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this you can get the answer:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","new");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO new values('nameuser','2015-09-12')");

// Print auto-generated id
echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($con);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Have a look at following links:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Also please have a note that this extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7.0

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in the above link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

The answer is:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (columnname) values ('$value')");        
echo $Id=mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: insecure `mysql` answer, never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... it worked for me!

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (row_name) VALUES('$row_value')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $msg1 = "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    $msg_error = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possible answer will be:

When you define the table, with the columns and data it'll have. The column id can have the property **AUTO_INCREMENT**.

By this method, you don't have to worry about the **id**, it'**ll be made automatically**.

For example (taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_autoincrement.asp) )

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone.

**Edit: This is only the part where you define how to generate an automatic ID, to obtain it after created, the previous answers before are right.**

Comment: this is not a possible answer at all, OP already states they are using auto-increment (auto increases). OP wants to retrieve that automatically generated id.

Comment: Okay, after reading again i've noticed that the problem is not only generating the id, OP also want to get that id. Thanks for the definition :D