# LAST_INSERT_ID() MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, last-insert-id

I have a MySQL question that I think must be quite easy. I need to return the LAST INSERTED ID from table1 when I run the following MySql query:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (title,userid) VALUES ('test',1); 
INSERT INTO table2 (parentid,otherid,userid) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),4,1);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

As you can understand the current code will just return the LAST INSERT ID of table2 instead of table1, how can I get the id from table1 even if I insert into table2 between?

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You could store the last insert id in a variable :

```
INSERT INTO table1 (title,userid) VALUES ('test', 1); 
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO table2 (parentid,otherid,userid) VALUES (@last_id_in_table1, 4, 1);
```

Or get the max id from table1 (EDIT: Warning. See note in comments from Rob Starling about possible errors from race conditions when using the max id)

```
INSERT INTO table1 (title,userid) VALUES ('test', 1); 
INSERT INTO table2 (parentid,otherid,userid) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 4, 1); 
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1;
```

(Warning: as Rob Starling points out in the comments)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't get it working first as I was using asp.net with MySQL and needed to add Allow User Variables=True to the Connection String to allow variables.

Comment: max is not a good idea, as you could lose a race with another inserter.

Comment: @RobStarling I totally agree, but in case somebody absolutely needs it; use a transaction with the proper isolation level.

Comment: what if 2 INSERTS happend at the same time or one before another?

Comment: @FosAvance LAST_INSERT_ID() is connection specific[ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14827987/1363495)

Comment: #Julien Hoarau what is the difference between SET @last_id_in_table1 = and SET last_id_in_table1 = ?

Comment: Using MAX() is not safe outside a transaction (i.e. autocommit enabled) and inside a transaction with a transaction isolation level below serializable. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Comment: It would be possible to save the @last_id_in_table1 variable into a php variable to use it later?

Comment: It would be possible to save the last_id_in_table1 variable into a php variable to use it later?

With this last_id I need to attach some records in another table with this last_id, so I need:

1) Do an INSERT and get the last_id_in_table1
     INSERT into Table1(name) values ("AAA");
     SET last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();

2) For any indeterminated rows in another table, UPDATING these rows with the last_id_insert generated in the insert.
     foreach (element as e){
          UPDATE Table2 SET column1 = last_id_in_table1 WHERE id in array()
     }

Comment: You should probably not use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after `INSERT IGNORE`. If there is a key collision, the new row will not be inserted and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return 0.

Comment: Not safe, use transaction on InnoDB engine. Or use ``LOCK TABLES`` see my post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51506539/2935383

Answer (score 26):

Since you actually stored the previous LAST_INSERT_ID() into the second table, you can get it from there:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (title,userid) VALUES ('test',1); 
INSERT INTO table2 (parentid,otherid,userid) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),4,1);
SELECT parentid FROM table2 WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 15):

This enables you to insert a row into 2 different tables and creates a reference to both tables too.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO accounttable(account_username) 
    VALUES('AnAccountName');
INSERT INTO profiletable(profile_account_id) 
    VALUES ((SELECT account_id FROM accounttable WHERE account_username='AnAccountName'));
    SET @profile_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
UPDATE accounttable SET `account_profile_id` = @profile_id;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Good shot on the transaction.

Comment: But: only available on InnoDB.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in bash and i'm doing something like this:

```
mysql -D "dbname" -e "insert into table1 (myvalue) values ('${foo}');"
```

which works fine:-) But

```
mysql -D "dbname" -e "insert into table1 (myvalue) values ('${foo}');set @last_insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();"
mysql -D "dbname" -e "insert into table2 (id_tab1) values (@last_insert_id);"
```

don't work. Because after the first command, the shell will be logged out from mysql and logged in again for the second command, and then the variable @last_insert_id isn't set anymore.
My solution is:

```
lastinsertid=$(mysql -B -N -D "dbname" -e "insert into table1 (myvalue) values ('${foo}');select LAST_INSERT_ID();")
mysql -D "dbname" -e "insert into table2 (id_tab1) values (${lastinsertid});"
```

Maybe someone is searching for a solution an bash :-)

Comment: ``LAST_INSERT_ID`` only available for the active connection.
``#mysq``-command connect for every command. You can connect with the ``mysql`` command to the server and insert your queries, or you can create a text file and you the ``mysql`` command with redirect from txt file aka ``mysql [connection option] < txt.file``

Answer (score 1):

We only have one person entering records, so I execute the following query immediately following the insert:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM corex ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $id = $row['id'];

}
```

This retrieves the last id from the database.

Comment: I had to give a valid example, so I used the one I use. If I had done it in C, you would probably have complained "not every one uses C" ....

Comment: Probably the safest and simplest out of all ;)

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to save the last_id_in_table1 variable into a php variable to use it later?

With this last_id I need to attach some records in another table with this last_id, so I need:

1) Do an INSERT and get the last_id_in_table1

```
INSERT into Table1(name) values ("AAA"); 
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

2) For any indeterminated rows in another table, UPDATING these rows with the last_id_insert generated in the insert.

```
$element = array(some ids)    
foreach ($element as $e){ 
         UPDATE Table2 SET column1 = @last_id_in_table1 WHERE id = $e 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For no InnoDB solution: you can use a procedure
`don't forgot to set the delimiter for storing the procedure with ;`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(OUT id INT, IN otherid INT, IN title VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
LOCK TABLES `table1` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `table1` ( `title` ) VALUES ( @title ); 
SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
UNLOCK TABLES;
INSERT INTO `table2` ( `parentid`, `otherid`, `userid` ) VALUES (@id, @otherid, 1); 
END
```

And you can use it...

```
SET @myid;
CALL myproc( @myid, 1, "my title" );
SELECT @myid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this `LAST_INSERT_ID()`
try to  use this one

```
mysqli_insert_id(connection)
```

Answer (score 1):

In trigger BEFORE_INSERT this working for me:

```
SET @Last_Insrt_Id = (SELECT(AUTO_INCREMENT /*-1*/) /*as  Last_Insert_Id*/ 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name = 'tblTableName' AND table_schema = 'schSchemaName');
```

Or in simple select:

```
SELECT(AUTO_INCREMENT /*-1*/) as Last_Insert_Id
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name = 'tblTableName' AND table_schema = 'schSchemaName');
```

If you want, remove the comment `/*-1*/` and test in other cases.
For multiple use, I can write a function. It's easy.

Answer (score 0):

For last and second last:

```
INSERT INTO `t_parent_user`(`u_id`, `p_id`) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(u_id-1) FROM user) ,(SELECT MAX(u_id) FROM user  ) );
```

Comment: This solution is not safe outside a transaction (i.e. autocommit enabled) and inside a transaction with a transaction isolation level below serializable. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Answer (score 0):

We could also use $conn->insert_id;
// Create connection

```
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
        echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

My code does not work for me. Any idea to recover the id of my last insert this is my code I am new developing and I do not know much

I GOT ERROR IN THE QUERY AND I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SEND PRINT IN THE LINE OF $ session-> msg ('s', "Product added successfully. Make cost configuration". LAST_INSERT_ID ());

ALREADY VERIFY AND IT IS CORRECT THE CONNECTION AND THE FIELDS OF THE DATABASE.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['add_producto'])){
  $req_fields = array( 'nombre', 'categoria', 'proveedor');
   validate_fields($req_fields);
   if(empty($errors)){
     $codigobarras  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['codigobarras']));
     $identificador   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['identificador']));
     $nombre   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['nombre']));
     $categoria   =  (int)$db->escape($_POST['categoria']);
     $etiquetas   =  remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['etiquetas']));
     $unidadmedida   =  remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['unidadmedida']));
     $proveedor   =  remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['proveedor']));
     $fabricante   =  remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['idfabricante']));
     $maximo   =  remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['maximo']));
     $minimo   =  remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['minimo']));
     $descripcion   =  remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['descripcion']));
     $dias_vencimiento   =  remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['dias_vencimiento']));
      
     $servicio   = "0";
      if (isset($_POST['servicio'])){
        $servicio =implode($_POST['servicio']);
     }
     $numeroserie   = "0"; 
      if (isset($_POST['numeroserie'])){
        $numeroserie =implode($_POST['numeroserie']);
     }

     $ingrediente   =  "0";
      if (isset($_POST['ingrediente'])){
        $ingrediente =implode($_POST['ingrediente']);
     }

     $date    = make_date();
     $query  = "INSERT INTO productos (";
     $query .=" codigo_barras,identificador_producto,nombre,idcategoria,idetiquetas,unidad_medida,idproveedor,idfabricante,max_productos,min_productos,descripcion,dias_vencimiento,servicio,numero_serie,ingrediente,activo";
     $query .=") VALUES (";
     $query .=" '{$codigobarras}', '{$identificador}', '{$nombre}', '{$categoria}', '{$etiquetas}', '{$unidadmedida}', '{$proveedor}', '{$fabricante}', '{$maximo}', '{$minimo}', '{$descripcion}', '{$dias_vencimiento}', '{$servicio}', '{$numeroserie}', '{$ingrediente}', '1'";
     $query .=");";
     $query .="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";

     if($db->query($query)){
      $session->msg('s',"Producto agregado exitosamente. Realizar configuracion de costos" . LAST_INSERT_ID());
       redirect('precio_producto.php', false);
     } else {
       $session->msg('d',' Lo siento, registro falló.');
       redirect('informacion_producto.php', false);
     }
   } else{
     $session->msg("d", $errors);
     redirect('informacion_producto.php',false);
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Alexander Suarez and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please use english?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have made the language change to English.  I hope you can help me with my code

Answer (score -2):

Just to add for Rodrigo post, instead of LAST_INSERT_ID() in query you can use SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1;, but you must use (),

```
INSERT INTO table1 (title,userid) VALUES ('test', 1)
INSERT INTO table2 (parentid,otherid,userid) VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1), 4, 1)
```

Comment: This solution is not safe outside a transaction (i.e. autocommit enabled) and inside a transaction with a transaction isolation level below serializable. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Answer (score -9):

If you need to have from mysql, after your query, the last auto-incremental id without another query, put in your code:

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Don't recommend mysql_* - those are deprecated

Comment: [cletus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus) got 106 upvotes and marked answer for **mysql_insert_id** here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/897361/153923

Comment: cletus answeed it in 2009! mysql is deprecated better to use mysqli and mysqli_insert_id http://ie2.php.net/mysqli_insert_id

Comment: Luca, If you'll delete this outdated answer, I believe your reputation points will be returned.

Comment: Another valid alternative to the deprecated suggestion is PDO::lastInsertId (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)