# AUTO_INCREMENT and LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: mysql

I'm using `AUTO_INCREMENT` and I would like to get that ID of inserted row so that I could update another table using `ID` as common field between the 2 tables.

I understood that `LAST_INSERT_ID` will get last `ID`. However, my concern is that, the database is accessed at same time by many users. Hence, there might be another process accessed the table and also inserted a new row at same time.

Does `LAST_INSERT_ID` return just the last ID regardless of the *connection* used, or only return last ID for the *connection* that I'm using?

Notice, I'm accessing MySQL database using connection pool in Tomcat server.

In summary, I need to insert a row in table A with auto increment, than I need to insert row in table B, which need to be linked to table A using the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.

Comment: Please provide more details then it will be helpful to answer.
but still you can Use KeyHolder.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT max(employeeid) FROM Employee;
```

The above query returns the value of `employeeid` of last inserted record in Employee table because `employeeid` is an auto increment column. This seems to be OK, but suppose two *threads* are executing insert operation simultaneously, there is a chance that you get wrong id of last inserted record!

Don’t worry, MySQL provides a function which returns the value of auto increment column of last inserted record.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

[`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is always **connection specific**, this means even if insert operation is carried out simultaneously from different connections, it always returns the value of current connection specific operation.

So you have to first insert record in Employee table, run the above query to get the id value and use this to insert in second table.

Comment: Thanks .. do I need to use transaction - setAutocommit(false) - in order for LAST_INSERT_ID to work. or it should works fine as long as I'm using same connection.

Comment: @user836026 to be safe, you can call this SET just after the INSERT no matter if in a transaction or not, then again the mention of transaction is more relevent to the MAX case that is more likely to yield desired result if invoked within a transaction, nonetheless, LAST_INSERT_ID is favored!

Answer (score 2):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` work in  **context**, it should be in transactions or  inside user defined stored procedures or user defined functions.

Comment: Thanks ... in Java, if I used set auto commit to false, and commit alter, it should do the job?

Answer (score 2):

`LAST_INSERT_ID` is connection specific. That's true, but you should be careful if you use connection pooling. This may be problematic when you perform successive `INSERT IGNORE` statements in a loop and the pool gives you the same connection at each iteration.

For example; Assume that you receive the same (open) connection for each of the below:

`INSERT IGNORE ...  some-new-id`   >>> `LAST_INSERT_ID` returns `100`

`INSERT IGNORE ...  some-existing-id`   >>> `LAST_INSERT_ID` still returns `100` (result of the previous operation)

It is always good to check whether the `INSERT` operation has in fact inserted any rows before calling `LAST_INSERT_ID`.

Comment: you mentioned `last_insert_id` has problem in connection pool, how to simulate this case? I try to test this case with spring, mybatis and c3p0 connection pool, set both `maxPoolSize` and `minPoolSize` as 1, insert multiple records in a loop with the help of thread. But I found that there is no problem in this case, the `last_insert_id` can get right result. Where is my test wrong or what I missed?

Comment: There are no issues if all the records you insert are new. But if your insert is IGNOREd and you call `last_insert_id`, the result returned may not belong to the most recent insert attempt. It might be the result of some other threads inserted some rows on the same connection. To be on safe side, check the result of the insert and call `last_insert_id` if necessary

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If `INSERT IGNORE` don't insert a record, then `last_insert_id` will return 0 or last insert id. This is not right result which we expected. So `last_insert_id` always has problem in `insert ignore` if there is no real insert no matter there is connection pool or not, right?

Comment: Yes you're right. But one difference is that with connection pooling you have to be careful even at your first `INSERT IGNORE` operation.

Answer (score 1):

`LAST_INSERT_ID` return the last insert id for the current session.
As long as you don't insert more than one entry with your current connection, it is valid.

Further information here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21181/is-mysqls-last-insert-id-function-guaranteed-to-be-correct

(i would link to mysql.com, but it'S currently down for me)

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID` is a global call? Is there no `LAST_INSERT_ID` for a specific table?

Comment: @user961627 One should always know, what table one has inserted to last within the current session.