# Insert two tables with one query?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert into two tables. I want to insert a name in to 'Names' and then insert a DVD into 'DVDs', using the id of the name inserted into 'Names'.

```
Names
id | name
1  | john

DVDs
id | title    | user_id
1  | Star Wars| 1
```

Updating the DVDs table depends on the insert id of the first insert.

Is there a way to do this in one query or would it need separating in to two quires?

Comment: what exactly do you want? update or insert? what is your desired output in the example above?

Comment: See this post that should answer your question [LAST_INSERT_ID() MySQL][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you mean:

```
INSERT INTO Names (name) VALUES ('john');
SET @last_id_Names = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO DVDs (title, user_id) VALUES (@last_id_Names, 'Star Wars');
```