# How to insert related data parts in two tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, insert

I have an employee table with

```
empID(name, address and dateOfBirth)
Position(positionID, positionName)
empPosition(empID, positionID, datePositionChanged, INDEX(empID), INDEX(positionID))
```

I have inserted in employee table as:

```
INSERT INTO `mario`.`employee` 
  (`empID`, `fName`, `lName`, `address`, `postCode`, `dateOfBirth`) 
VALUES 
  (NULL, 'Paul', 'Roberts', '221 heaventown street', '1994-12-01');
```

and in position table as:

```
INSERT INTO `mario`.`position` 
  (`positionID`, `positionName`, `datePositionChanged`) 
VALUES 
  (NULL, 'Manager', '2013-12-01');
```

Obviously, there is no relationship between Paul and manager. Any suggestions on how should I insert it ?

(I am very new student; just learning in mySQL).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Not when it's a *many-to-many* relationship (hence the `empPosition` [*junction table*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table))

Comment: @Phil I skipped over the `empPosition` when scanning the text. (didn't read the question thoroughly)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LAST\_INSERT\_ID() MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql). See the first part of the accepted answer (setting a variable)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I want the position and employee to have many to many relationship based on time.

Comment: @Phil , It doesnt look similar, as i understand. Any help be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the IDs in the `employee` and `position` tables are auto-increment (hence the `NULL` insert values), you would insert into the first (`employee`) and save the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` into a variable. Rinse / repeat for `position` (saving into a different variable) then insert both saved IDs into `empPosition`.

Answer (score 1):

If your position table will be like the master table for all possible positions assign a position Id for each row and empPosition table you can have a mapping between employee and position.

INSERT INTO `mario`.`position` 
  (`positionID`, `positionName`, `datePositionChanged`) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Manager', '2013-12-01');

INSERT INTO `mario`.`employee` 
  (`empID`, `fName`, `lName`, `address`, `postCode`, `dateOfBirth`) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Paul', 'Roberts', '221 heaventown street', '1994-12-01');

INSERT INTO `mario`.empPosition'
('empID', 'positionID') values (1,1);

Answer (score -1):

It seems Table Position should has a primary key of something like PositionId. This is then inserted into empPosition. In other words empPosition is sort of a look-up table which references the primary keys EmployeeId and PositionId. This table can then be queried to get a position by employeeId, etc.

Comment: positionID and empID are primary keys in position and employee tables.