# Simultaneous inserting in MySQL(innodb)

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-concurrency

Consider we have a table `t_log` in database `Test`. The t_log looks like the following

```
create table `t_log`(
`F_log_id` bigint(20) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
`F_trans_id` bigint(20) not null,
`F_action` tinyint(3) not null,
primariy key(`F_log_id`)
)engine=innodb
```

Suppose `F_action` field can only take several specific values,like 1 and 2. For `F_action`=1 records, coresponding `F_trans_id` must differ from each other. While for `F_action`=2 records, coresponding `F_trans_id` can take same values.

For example records like the following in table should be valid

```
F_log_id | F_action | F_trans_id
  1            1          1001
  2            2          1002
  3            2          1002
```

However records like the following should not be valid

```
F_log_id | F_action | F_trans_id
  1            1          1001
  2            1          1001
  3            2          1002
```

Since our unique restriction on `F_trans_id` depends on the specific value of `F_action`, we cannot merely build the unique index on F_trans_id and F_action.

For consistency, inserting records into t_log is put into a transaction like this

```
start_transaction()
select and check if valid
do inserting
commit()
```

However in high-concurrency environment, there might be two inserting transaction arrived almost at the same time, for example, both entered start_transaction(), suppose two records are both (F_action=1, F_trans_id=222), when select and check, both found record is valid and insert it. Then `t_log` will have invalid two records.

Is there any good way two prevent this kind of invalid records? Thank you.

Comment: How do you pick the value for F_trans_id?. It's not mentioned in the question and it is important.

Comment: @LHristov, F_trans_id is picked from other tables. For example, this procedure may served as an interface called by other program， and F_trans_id will be passed as input parameters, generated or picked by external program

Comment: Cant you clear that picking algorithm? Or just set value to F_trans_id in the transaction, I mean create a table where it is autoincrement, make an insert to that table and get it back with `last_insert_id`. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql)

Comment: @LHristov, there's no such picking algorithm. you may think F_trans_id was pass by some external app, and the external app may pass any kind of F_trans_id(which we may hardly predicted). One of our target is to avoid repeatly simultaneous call. by saying *repeatly*, I mean two simultaneous call by the external app with F_action=1 and F_trans_id with same value

Answer (score 0):

Use arithmetic to generate unique values as required:

- create a new column, say `action_hash int`
- create a unique index on `(F_trans_id, action_hash)`
- create a trigger that populates `action_hash` with distinct values when needed

In your example, the simplest thing I can think of is:

```
new.action_hash = new.F_log_id * (new.F_action - 1)
```

Which will be zero when `F_action` is `1`, this requiring F_trans_id to be unique, but otherwise not.

Comment: Thank you, @Bohemian, but this rather tricky(action_hash formula totally depends on specific value interpretation of action!).. Is there some more general way to this problem(I think this should be a very common requirements in mysql)? for example I tried to do select for update specfic row, but the delay between select and insert, and the RR transaction Isolation level in innodb make this won't work. thanks any way.

Comment: Yes it is a solution for specific values of `F_action`, but isn't that the whole point of the question? Only when `F_action` is 1, must the other column be unique? If that's not the question, please clarify.