# Using where id = last_insert_id() returns empty result set

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch a row of data in mysql after inserting a row of data in mysql table using

`SELECT * FROM incoming_sms WHERE id = last_insert_id();` but this returns an empty set of results although i have indeed inserted a new row and my table contains data.

How can i make my query return some data?.

Comment: [LAST_INSERT_ID() MySQL][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql

Try this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normative pattern is to execute a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` statement *immediately* following the successful insert statement, from the *same session* that issue the `INSERT` statement.

There are several possible reasons that what you are attempting is not working. I've not seen the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function used in a SELECT statement like you have it; I'm not sure if the behavior is defined. I've just never seen it used like that.

The normal pattern is:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col) VALUES (val);
-- check if statement succeeded; if it successfully inserted a row
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
-- retrieve returned value
```

Then use the retrieved value in subsequent processing.

Note (again) that the reference to `LAST_INSERT_ID()` **must** be made **from the same session** that performed the INSERT, and should be performed before **any** other SQL statement is issued.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: If i am using `new.id`,does the same rule apply for the session and before any other sql statement ?

Comment: @user3272483: No. In the context of an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, the `NEW.id` identifier is a reference to the value that was stored in the id column for the row.  You can perform other SQL statements in the trigger body, the `NEW.id` identifier still references the value stored in the id column of the current row.

Comment: @user3272383: The original question omits any mention of a trigger. In an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, the normal pattern for retrieving the value assigned to an auto_increment column is to reference `NEW.id` (or, NEW. whatever the name of the auto_increment column is.)