# SQL, select last insert ID by LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I didn't find an exact answer so I try to ask here.
I running an SQL INSERT Query and after that I want to use the ID of the
this INSERT Query, I found this: LAST_INSERT_ID() and it's work, but I thinking what would happen if I not the only one who run the query on the server I can get a wrong ID from the DB, so there is other to take the last ID ?

Comment: If you are using LAST_INSERT_ID() in the insert query, you should not worry about that because the both operations (getting the last ID and insertion) will happen in the context of a single transaction.

Comment: Take a look at this other post that deals with the same scenario.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should return the last inserted row id from the same connection. So if other user has inserted another row in between, LAST_INSERT_ID function will still return the relevant idfor the first user.

Quoting from mysql documentation:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function(LAST_INSERT_ID) to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client

Here is the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id .

Comment: Great, that answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

This is both an answer and a clarification of the misconceptions presented elsewhere in this Q&A.

After you do an INSERT into a table with an AUTO_INCREMENT, the value of that AI is waiting for you in *that connection*; you can fetch it via LAST_INSERT_ID (or whatever synonym your client's API has).

It is tied to the *connection*, not a transaction.

Being tied to the connection, no *other connection* can accidentally get the id that you just created.

MAX(id) *does* run the risk of another connection INSERTing another row, thereby bumping id beyond the value you just inserted.  Hence, MAX(id) *could* give you the wrong value.

If you need to do INSERT..ON DUPLICATE UPDATE, the online manual has a clear example of how to get the id of the row, whether it was INSERTed or UPDATEd.  It requires that you the kludgy looking `id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` in the UPDATE part.

The only requirement for an AUTO_INCREMENT be that it is the *first* column in *some* index, not necessarily the PRIMARY KEY.  (MyISAM has an exception, for which InnoDB has no counterpart.)  What you *could* lose by not saying PRIMARY KEY(id) is the prevention of duplicate ids when you *explicitly* INSERT the *same* id again.

Answer (score 0):

you can get last id from your table like this it would be better if id is auto increment

```
Select max(id) from yourtable
```

Comment: This could be problematic if multiple people are using the system at the same time. There is no guarantee the max(id) will return the desired id.