# Can an auto-incremented value in MySQL be preserved?

Tags: mysql

How do I preserve the `last_insert_id()` into a specific record?
Here are my queries:

```
INSERT INTO student(student_name) VALUES ('ramgopal')`;   
SELECT `last_insert_id()`;   
INSERT INTO grades (student_id,grade) VALUES (last_insert_id(),'A');   
INSERT INTO class (semester,day,time) VALUES ('spring 2015','tuesday','12');   
SELECT last_insert_id();  
insert INTO grades(class_id) VALUES (last_insert_id());
```

In grade table I got `grade_id`, `class_id`, `student_id` and `grade` records.

When I use the `last_insert_id()` again it is just inserting the latest id and the previous id is not inserting. So I would like to preserve the initial `last_insert_id` for further use.

Comment: Check out this; I think it answers your question:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql

Comment: But this is inserting values one after the other not simultaneously.

Comment: it might be easier to do with your application layer;  you could easily assign the value to a variable, and then just call that variable when you need it, and reset with new rows

Comment: `set @student_id = last_insert_id();` `insert into grades (student_id, grade) values (@student_id, 'A');`