# how to use primary key as custId number in second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, the first has an auto incrementing ID number, I want to use that as custId in the second table. 
I am using an insert into the first table with all the basic info, name, address etc. Then in the second table only 3 things, custId, stocknum, and location. How can I write to these two tables kinda of simultaneously since stockNum may have several values, but always attached to one custId. I hope this makes sense even without putting code in here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't do it kind of simultaneously, you write into one first and then into the other in two different queries. If you share your code we can try and figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert into multiple tables at the same time. You have two options. You either do two inserts

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES ('value1',value2);
/* Gets the id of the new row and inserts into the other table */
INSERT INTO table2 (cust_id, stocknum, location) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'value3', 'value4')
```

Or you can use a post-insert trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER table2_auto AFTER INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table2 (cust_id, stocknum, location) VALUES (NEW.id, value3, 'value4')
END
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I looked into that LAST_INSERT_ID() thing, because I wondered if I had two people writing at the same time if it could be a race I don't wanna be in.  But it seems that is connection specific and so far it is working. I did not even try the trigger action. Thank you for your input even though I included no Code.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting in the first table, The identity field or Auto increment field generate an ID

Get this id      Refer Here([LAST_INSERT_ID() MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql))

Then use this id to store value in the other table