# INSERT values from one table to another with the new id and coping new id to another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have sql query:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, username, email, params, password )
SELECT CONCAT (`IMIE_WL`,' ', `NAZ_WL`), 
       CONCAT (a.wid,'-',LPAD(a.cid, 4, '0') ,'-',LPAD(a.LP_H, 2, '0')),
       b.AK_NAZWA,
       CONCAT('{"language":"","helpsite":""}'),
       CONCAT('SomePasswordSalted')
FROM   source_data AS b
INNER JOIN loginy AS a ON a.ID_LOK = b.ID_LOK;
```

I need add to this another insert to this query like this:

```
INSERT INTO conector (id,ID_LOK) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),ID_LOK);
```

Any ideas for one query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LAST\_INSERT\_ID() MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql)

Comment: Short answer: You can't merge two separated insert's into one query.

Comment: I understand : can't use last_insert_id in my query.