# how to get id from table in php

Tags: php, html

```
table 'orders'(id,name,phone,price,adress,status)

table orders_foods (id, food_id, order_id, price, quantity)
```

i need to insert in to orders_foods and i need order_id auto generate when i klik **tambah pesanan** (Add order)

[home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQRoG.png)
When i klik tambah pesan then show modal for insert into orders_food

[modal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLldB.png)

evry coloumn have button **tambah pesanan** (Add Order) how i can get id from that coloumn for insert into my orders_foods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LAST\_INSERT\_ID() MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql)

Comment: Are you using a framework or just plain PHP?

Comment: i use only php no frame work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ID like this (this is the html or twig template ***tableEntries.twig***:

```html
<html>
<head>Get ID</head>
<body>
  <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <td>column id</td>
              <td>column name</td>
              <td>column description</td>
              <td>column note</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for someAlias in dataExample %} <!-- dataExample is an array in the php file -->
        <tbody>
            <tr>
<!-- *columnID*, *columnName*, etc. are 
the real mysql columns, while **someAlias** 
is just a random name for this for-loop. 
**dataExample** is the array which contains 
all the values of the corresponding columns -->
                <td>{{ someAlias.columnID }}</td>
                <td>{{ someAlias.columnName }}</td>
                <td>{{ someAlias.columnDescription }}</td>
                <td>{{ someAlias.columnNote }}</td>
            </tr>
        <td>
    <!-- The php script parses the mysql database 
and saves the id and all other values in an array. 
The php templating engine Twig uses this file as 
its template (frontend). 
If the Send-Button is pressed, the id will be 
saved inside $_POST["SecretIdUsedForIfSendButtonIsPressed"]; 
and can be used to add, edit or delete table entries (rows) 
from there. -->
         <form method="POST" action="addTableEntries.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="SecretIdUsedForIfSendButtonIsPressed" value="{{ SecretIdParsedFromTheMySqlDatabase }}">
          <input type="submit" value="tambah pesanan">
        </form>
       </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php script ***tableEntries.php*:**

```
<?php
/* Lists all column entries inside your mysql table(s)
 * Author: timunix
 * Date: 10.07.2018
*/
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // you don't need to change the path, just leave it like that, twig will do the job for you
require_once "utils/Database.class.php"; // include database configuration

// init twig
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('template/'); /*no path adaptation needed, just leave it like that, twig will "know" where your twig/html templates are*/

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    "debug" => "true",
));
include "utils/injector.php";

$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());

/* ------- */

DatabaseLink::getInstance()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// fetch data from database *(simple way, not entirely safe, though!)*
$stmt = DatabaseLink::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_columns WHERE columnID > 0");
$columnData = $stmt->fetchAll();

//template values
$templateName = "tableEntries.twig";
$data = array(
    "dataExample" => $columnData,
);

//display
echo $twig->render($templateName, $data);
```

If you have any questions, just ask me.