# Insert row, get id from inserted row and use it in new insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Is there a way to insert a row, get the inserted id and use it in the next query all this in just one single query?

```
INSERT INTO tableA (eID, name, otherStuff) VALUES (NULL, 'emailName', 'otherValues');
SET @tableA_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO tableB (id, emailId, body, name, langId) VALUES (NULL, @tableA_id, 'email text', 'Default', '1');
INSERT INTO tableB (id, emailId, body, name, langId) VALUES (NULL, @tableA_id, 'other language text', 'Default', '2');
```

In the previous code segment, there are three separate queries and when I execute them in my sql editor it gives me an error here: `SET @tableA_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Again, there are 3 separate queries here, is there a way to have something like a subquery in order to achieve this?

Comment: What is the error?  Are you declaring the variable first?  Can you insert null into the eID field?  We need error details

Comment: @Brad there's no specific error. This is what I'm getting back: ```[ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1```

Comment: But, there's no code `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` within the block you presented in the question.

Comment: Yes there is @BarbarosÖzhan, it's after the first `INSERT INTO`. Second line

Comment: No, that's `SET @tableA_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. It was a copy/paste mistake. Already corrected. The error's still there

Comment: The error is coming from `SET`. If I execute only `LAST_INSERT_ID()` I'm getting a value, but if I run `SET @tableA_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` that's when I get the error

Answer (score 0):

You could store the last insert id in a variable :

```
INSERT INTO table1 (title,userid) VALUES ('test', 1); 
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO table2 (parentid,otherid,userid) VALUES 
(@last_id_in_table1, 4, 1);    
Or get the max id frm table1

INSERT INTO table1 (title,userid) VALUES ('test', 1); 
INSERT INTO table2 (parentid,otherid,userid) VALUES 
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 4, 1); 
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1;
```

Or
We have inserted 3 records above. Therefore, the next id must be 4.

The following is the syntax to know the next id.

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "yourDatabaseName"
AND TABLE_NAME = "yourTableName"
```

Comment: Please don't copy code from [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql/3838011#3838011) without attribution.