# how to select last autoincrement id using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)

I have an inset command such as

```
insert (name) values($name);
```

I have id column as autoincrement. How can I get the id of the inserted record *after* inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert (name) values($name);
SET @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
select blah_blah from table where id = @lastid;
```

To get that back into php, you do a normal mysql select on it like this:

```
select @lastid;
```

Answer (score 0):

For mysql you can use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the id of the last inserted row.