# How to get a Primary ID before or at the same time it gets created?

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

What I am doing: (wp_posts has ID as primary key and it auto-increase)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_content, post_title) VALUES ('$addEP', '$title')");
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title='$title'");
$add_row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$add_postid = $add_row['ID'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id) VALUES ('$add_postid', '$cat_id')");
```

So basically, what I am doing is; I insert content into wp_posts and then run another query to catch the `ID` of the post. Then set it into another table.

Is it possible to do this without running the second query to catch the ID?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$add_postid = mysql_insert_id();` is what you are looking for.

So

```
$rs = ... // and
$add_row = ...
```

... is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the last generated id (per connection) via [mysql_insert_id()](http://docs.php.net/function.mysql-insert-id)

edit: The MySQL server also stores that id per connection and you can ["retrieve" the id *within* an sql statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

```
INSERT INTO
  wp_term_relationships
  (object_id, term_taxonomy_id)
VALUES
  (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$cat_id')
```

There are subtle difference between the two "methods" which are explained at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html

Answer (score 1):

that's what [`mysql_last_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) is for

Comment: I think you have a typo there. Thanks for the link, this is what i was looking for =)

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_insert_id()`](http://ca.php.net/mysql_insert_id) will return the value for you, but only AFTER the insert as completed. You can't use it within an insert to catch the new ID, because that ID won't have been assigned yet.

Internally it's doing `select last_insert_id();`.

Answer (score 1):

Without passing the `ID` of the post manually, you would have to use [mysql_insert_id()](http://us.php.net/mysql_insert_id).

> Note:
>
> Because mysql_insert_id() acts on the last performed query, be sure to
>   call mysql_insert_id() immediately after the query that generates the
>   value.

On a side note, I would suggest you check out [PDO](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if you have not already.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of (you have to insert before you can get the right id)...where is the script being ran? Wordpress has a built in class that would perhaps make it easier, it has a variable that stores the insert ID as well:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Class_Variables