# how to get the Auto increment id of Query that is just inserted in the db?

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is Weird actually sorry if i'm asking something stupid but i just want to know if it can be done or not....

```
Add.php
<form method="post" action="info.php">
<input name="Car_name" type="text">
<input name="Car_color" type="text">
<button type="submit" name="save" > save </button>
</form>
```

this page is add.php from here a post request is generated to page message.php. In this page we pass the Query like this..

```
Message.php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
mysql_query("insert into Car_data where Car_name='".$_POST['Car_name']."',Car_color='".$_POST['Car_color']."'");
}
```

but i want to print the Auto incremented id of this inserted data..
For once i thought i can take a condition where i can check `$_POST['Car_name']&&$_POST['Car_color']` but there can be many car with same color and name like red Ferrari.. Some is there any possible way to get id of that element just inserted ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a Primary ID before or at the same time it gets created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192449/how-to-get-a-primary-id-before-or-at-the-same-time-it-gets-created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call mysql_insert_id() after your insert (it returns the last inserted ID)

Answer (score 2):

To get the last inserted id you use [mysql_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id)

```
mysql_query("insert into Car_data where Car_name='".$_POST['Car_name']."',Car_color='".$_POST['Car_color']."'");

$last_id = mysql_insert_id() ;
```

But as its suggested use mysqli_* functions and can use [mysqli_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id) function to get the last inserted id