# PHP/MySQL Get autoincremented value after insert

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql table i have an id-column which is set to autoincrement.

then i do queries like this:

INSERT INTO table (id, foo) VALUES ('', 'bar')

how can i then safely find out which id was generated with this insert?

if i just query the last id this might not be safe, since another insert could have happened in the meantime, right?

Comment: Wrong. The LAST ID will be the last id that has been inserted using that connection. Unless you share the connection, that will be the statement that just happened. So `INSERT INTO; SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID` will be good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)

Comment: yep sorry it is a duplicate of that other question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a PHP and also a MySQL function for this: **`mysqli_insert_id()`** and **`PDO::lastInsertId()`**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: It should be noted that the PHP method is being deprecated, so it would be wise to use the MySQL method from here on out.

Comment: @RCNeil hey guys, say you have multiple concurrent visitors on your website, wouldnt using `mysqli_insert_id()` run into issues if two `inserts` are executed almost immediately after one another for different users?

Comment: If the query is executed successfully, the `mysqli_insert_id()` function will return the ID generated from that specific query, so you can assign it to a variable and continue to do something with it right after and be fine.  It's not pulling "the last ID put in the table", it's pulling the ID that was just made with that specific query in that specific connection - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38957080/884953

Answer (score 4):

Use  [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in SQL

```
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Use  [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) in PHP

Comment: wouldnt `mysqli_insert_id()` run into issues if there are multiple concurrent users on your website, and two `inserts` are executed almost immediately one after the other? is there a way to combine the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` with the `INSERT INTO...` statement, and then fetch the value with PHP, to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP to get the auto_incremented value that is returned after an INSERT statement, try using the [MySQLi `insert_id` function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).  The older `mysql_insert_id()` version is being deprecated in PHP.

An example below:

```
 <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);

/* drop table */
$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE myCity");

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you use mysql_query("..."), then [mysql_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) is the function you need. If you use something else to do queries, then the corresponding documentation should be checked

Answer (score 2):

Be Careful when using mysql_insert_id() specially if you have multiple connections to the Database. Because It doesn't get the value of the query you've inserted. it gets the latest id of the table. It may be a row another query has inserted. Only use this function if you access Database in one connection.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_insert_id();
```

You can also simply run this query:

```
INSERT INTO table (foo) VALUES ('bar')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's PHP, [mysql_insert_id](http://ch2.php.net/mysql_insert_id) should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the rather good example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 1):

**Simple method**

Insert data :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, foo) VALUES ('', 'bar')";
$conn->query($sql)
```

Get ID :

```
return $conn->insert_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

also in PDO after the execute command as the example below:

```
$lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

click for [REF](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: apparently [there are issues](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php#122009) with this approach