# Is mysqli_insert_id() gets record from whole server or from same user?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have mysql question that `mysqli_insert_id()` returns record from overall server or from specific user who has inserted that id? Because if it returns from overall then it won't be secure to use this function

Comment: Then is it secure to use it?

Comment: Yes why wouldn't it be secure to use?

Comment: Because it can return record of other user

Comment: if you're not using a prepared statement, then yeah; your code is not secure.

Comment: @ZainFarooq - it's safe! It's tied explicitly to the connection, and only one user has that connection at a time

Comment: @Fred-ii What prepared statements can do if its returns record from all users?

Comment: @Mark Baker. Here some says that it returns record from all users

Comment: I said that because I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, nor do we know under which circumstance it's being used. If they say it's safe, then *"as you were"* applies ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-. Ok. But it does not depend on the rest of the code and probably It can't be

Comment: It's safe to say, yes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I understand the gesture " It's safe to say, yes " lol!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment from @daan above is flat-out wrong. `insert_id()` returns the ID placed into an auto_increment field of the last `insert` query that the connection executing the insert_id() query performed.

It does not return the largest ID in the table, it doesn't return the id created by some OTHER connection, it doesn't return the id created by some OTHER user.

It is literally the last ID **YOU** created by the **LAST** insert **YOU** performed.

That means it is 100% reliable to perform an insert, get the created ID via `last_insert_id()` and then use that ID in other queries to create parent/child records.

But note that `insert_id()` only ever returns **ONE** id value. If you do a multi-value insert, you still only get the ID from the last value set, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO sometable (x, y) VALUES (1,2), (2,3)
```

still performs two inserts internally, and you'd only get the id for the `2,3` tuple, not the `1,2`.

As well, there's no memory for all previous queries:

```
INSERT ...   // query #1
INSERT ...   // query #2
SET id = last_insert_id();
```

will only get the ID created by query #2, and the ID from query #1 is "lost".

Comment: Ok. I want to know that how does it differentiate users on the server?

Comment: I don't see Daan's comment; he might have deleted it. I don't remember seeing it myself so that should be taken out.

Comment: @ZainFarooq: because it's tied to a specific connection. even if your code holds open multiple simultaneous connections to the DB, the id function KNOWS which connection it's been called in, and will only ever return the ID generated by that particular connection.

Comment: @MarcB: But connection is always same by every user when it connects to the server and database.

Comment: no. it's not. the communications protocol is the same, but every connection by itself is unique/distinct. Every connection basically gets its own internal ID number, and that will never get duplicated across multiple connections. Even if you connect 2+ times in the same script using the same credentials, the connections will STILL have different internal identifiers. and don't bother arguinga bout this. if insert_id() was a "global" id, it'd be an utter useless function, and it would be impossible to reliably retrieve generated IDs. It works. It's 100% reliable. End of story.

Comment: Ok.. I got it.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@ZainFarooq Before executing the function mysqli_insert_id() there is something called mysqli_connect() function in the php to connect to the server and then select the database to fetch records.
 In case of mysqli_insert_id() function yes it's completely safe to use and it returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.