# MYSQL & PHP Saving LAST_INSERT_ID() as a local variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some issues with storing data in  database from a PHP form. The form calls a file called insert which I have copied below. Basically, I need to store details into the table scout and save the last_insert_id() as a local variable to be used when I insert items into the table emergencyContact. Then the emergencycontacts last_insert_id() needs to be saved and then stored in the scout table. However at the moment it is not working. I don't think I have storing/using the variable correct yet.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("lex", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Scout (Unit_id, FirstName, SurName, DOB, Address, Telephone, School, Religion, Ethenic, Child_Doc, Doc_Phone, Allergies, Active)
VALUES ('$_POST[unitid]','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[school]','$_POST[religion]','$_POST[ethnicidentity]','$_POST[doctorsname]','$_POST[doctorsnumber]','$_POST[health]','$_POST[radio]')");

mysql_query("SET @scout_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO EmergencyContact (Scout_id, Name, Tel, Address) 
VALUES(@scout_id,'$_POST[emergencycontact]','$_POST[emergencyphone]',$_POST[emergencyaddress]')");

mysql_query("SET @emergency_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: No need to pull it in a query. Its available to PHP with [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: So would I just write:
    SET @scout_id =  mysql_insert_id();
?

Comment: No, you don't need to do it with MySQL variables at all. Just insert it into your second `INSERT` query as `"INSERT INTO EmergencyContact(Scout_id, Name, Tel, Address) VALUES (" . mysql_insert_id() . " other,values,...)"`

Comment: Note that your query is _highly_ vulnerable to SQL injection. At a minimum, you _must_ call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each of those `$_POST` query inputs. Consider switching to an API that supports prepared statements, like MySQLi or PDO. The mysql_*() functions are being deprecated in PHP 5.5

Comment: I need to store them in local variables as after I save stuff into Scouts (insert_id will be the last scoutId) I will then insert this id with other details into emergencyContact and insert_id will then be the emergencyContact ID. I then save the emergencyContactID + ScoutID into another table so need a way of keeping track of scoutID

Comment: I understand, but what I am saying (and what is conventionally done) is to store them in local variables on the PHP side rather than in the RDBMS.  It is far simpler.  After your first query, save it as `$scout_id = mysql_insert_id();` to use in the second. After your second query, you can do `$emerg_contact_id = mysql_insert_id();` to use later as well.  This is a very common practice.

Comment: Thank you! My fault, I misunderstood, I was missing ' ' after I edited it so everythings working now. Thanks again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_insert_id()`

```
$idInsertLast = mysql_insert_id();
```

the result is the last AUTOINCREMENT id inserted from this connection/user.  if you have 200 different users doing insert transactions around the same time, each will receive his/her last id, not anyone else's, even if between the time userA inserts a record and the time he/she calls mysql_insert_id(), userB and userC have inserted records of their own.

be careful not to share connections between users, as long as each user opens his/her own connection to DB, everything will be fine.

NOTE: mysql_query and the rest of the library have been deprecated and will eventually be removed from future php versions.