# How to get the ID as the record is inserted?

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting record into database using the insert query as

`INSERT INTO task_record(assigned_by,handle_by) VALUES('$assigned_by', '$handle_by')`

adding this record assign a unique ID to the each record i want to get that ID as soon as the record is inserted.
Is there any simple way to modify the query or i have to use one more query of select which is not a fine option

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` for direct sql, and lookup the api specific info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id

Comment: i have tried with this `echo  $id = mysql_insert_id();`
i have right this line after the data is inserted 
but its returning 0

Comment: Show us more of your PHP code, including the actual code used to make the query. (there are several possible answers to your question; we need to see more of your code in order to know which one is correct)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$this->db->insert_id()` like

```
echo "The Last Insert Id is ".$this->db->insert_id();
```

Or like

```
echo "The Last Insert Id is ".$this->insert_id();
```

Or even simply

```
echo "The Last Insert Id is ".mysql_insert_id();
```

But try to avoid using `mysql_*` functions due to they are deprecated.Instead use either `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` statements.

**EDIT:**

```
$query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() task_id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['task_id'];
}
echo $id;
```

Comment: its returning 0 using the statment  `echo "The Last Insert Id is ".mysql_insert_id();
`

Comment: Are you getting result from first two..??

Comment: Last one also give the inserted id..You may done wrong in insert query.check once

Comment: sorry to say but its not working and !st two are returning an error of undefined method which they are

Comment: record is being inserted but id is returning to be 0

Comment: Do you have an auto increment field in your table..??

Comment: yes i have the feild of `task id` as auto incremented

Answer (score 0):

If your interfacing with mysql directly execute `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` after the insert query.

with the now obsolote mysql extension you could execute `mysql_insert_id();`

with the mysql improved extension use `mysqli_insert_id();`

Comment: which parameter is to be passed to the `mysqli_insert_id();` ?

Comment: its giving an error if its left Empty