# How to get current rows data after inserting element.

Tags: php

I have four fields in table id, name, city & state. I am inserting name , city & state. and id is auto increament

```
$mysql_register_resultset= mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into vendor (username, city, state) VALUES( '$name','$city','$state')");
```

It is successfully sumitted. I want that id value on next line of insertion. and i will process with that id.

How to get current id after insertion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
$last_inserted_id =  mysqli_insert_id($con) ;
```