# SQL get the ID from the row that was just inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I get the ID of the row that I just inserted?  I am using a PDO statement where I can insert a name and email into a table.

```
$dbh = new PDO();
$dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO `table` (`name`, `email`) VALUES (:name, :email);");
// execute
$dbh->execute(array(':name' => 'John Doe', ':email' => 'johndoe@gmail.com'));
```

The table also has an auto increment id column.

How can I get the id of the row that was just created?  I have read about `lastInsertId()`, but won't that sometimes give the wrong value if two clients insert a row at the same time?

Comment: no. if lastInsertId() got "confused" like that, it'd be utterly useless. It'll always return the ID of the LAST insert that YOU have done.

Comment: Typo? Change `:value` to `:email` in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastInsertId()` returns last inserted id for this DB conection. In other page will be another connection and another last inserted id.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @Issam Zoli
[this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) may be what you need. Seems to have some caveats though.

Check out [NaturalBornCamper's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id).

Here's an example of how to use it from the links above.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$statement = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO people(name, city) VALUES(:name, :city)');
$statement->execute( array(':name' => 'Bob', ':city' => 'Montreal') );

echo $db->lastInsertId();
```