# MySQL-Query: Refer to last inserted row from another table (just with one php-SQL String)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to put a new row into the database AND refer to this row in a second table. Does anyone have an idea how to do it (using just one php: mysql_query?).

Starting two queries for this purpose is too risky, because the connection can be lost between them.

Idea:

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO `tbl_humpahumpa`(`humpa_txt`) VALUES ('Ring Ring Ring Bananafon!'); 
INSERT INTO `tbl_reference_to_humpa`(`humpa_ref_id`) VALUES (' ??? referenceid ??? ');";
```

Comment: Using [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) should help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) cannot execute multiple queries at once, You can use [SQL Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), for example :-

```
try{
  mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_humpahumpa`(`humpa_txt`) VALUES ('Ring Ring Ring Bananafon!')");
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_reference_to_humpa`(`humpa_ref_id`) VALUES ('".mysqli_insert_id()."')");
  mysql_query("COMMIT;")
} catch (Exception $e) {
  mysql_query("ROLLBACK;");
}
```

or [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_humpahumpa`(`humpa_txt`) VALUES ('Ring Ring Ring Bananafon!');
INSERT INTO `tbl_reference_to_humpa`(`humpa_ref_id`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());"; // Done
```

MySQL provides a function called LAST_INSERT_ID() that returns the last auto_increment ID for the current session.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id