# mySQL: insert values into 2 tables with foreign key relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

I have created 2 tables with the following structure:

```
mitarbeiter
==================
maID (PK, AUTO_INCREMENT, NOT NULL)
maAnrede
maName
maVname
maDurchwahl
maEmail
maMobilfunkNr
maKartenanzahl
maFirma

mobilfunkkarten
==============================
mfkID (PK, AUTO_INCREMENT, NOT NULL)
mfkTarif
mfkStatus
mfkKartennr
mfkPin
mfkSuperpin
maID(FK)
```

Now I would like the web user to type in values into form fields. After clicking the "Save"-Button, the data will be saved into the corresponding 2 tables.
My mySQL-Query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO mitarbeiter,mobilfunkkarten
(maAnrede, maVname, maName, maMobilfunkNr, mfkTarif, maKartenanzahl, mfkStatus, mfkkartennr, mfkPin, mfkSuperpin, maEmail, maFirma) 
VALUES($anrede, $Vorname, $Nachname,.......);
```

Unfortunately, the query doesn't work because you can't use 2 tables after the INSERT command like in my example.

Any solutions on how to solve this? I just can't think of any way on how to make sure that anything the user types into the form fields will be saved as 1 dataset into these 2 tables, i.e. the NEW data in the child table 'mobilfunkkarten' will be related to the Primary Key Number in the parent table 'mitarbeiter'.

mitarbeiter = workers
mobilfunkkarten = mobile phone cards (SIM cards)

Comment: It will take two queries because you need to get the key from the related row to insert into the parent row. You can do this in a transaction so that if something fails, you can rollback the insert.

Comment: Also, be sure to use parameterized queries with either mysqli or PDO functions to avoid SQL injection and to properly handle quotes.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id) on how to get the primary key back from an INSERT

Comment: @SloanThrasher: First of all, thank you. Please don't let us worry about the SQL injection, though. I am using a templating engine that does all the work for me. All I need is the SQL query syntax for my problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First insert the employees.

```
INSERT INTO mitarbeiter
            (maanrede,
             ...)
            VALUES(?,
                   ...);
```

Then insert the SIM card. Use [`last_insert_id()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to get the ID created for the employee record.

```
INSERT INTO mobilfunkkarten
            (mfktarif,
             ...,
             maID)
            VALUES (?,
                    ...,
                    last_insert_id());
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks a lot! Perhaps you should remove/delete unnecessary code like "maMobilfunkNr, mfkTarif,...." in your post to round it up.