# mysql using lastInsertID in the same mysql insert?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I am inserting a single row into a table, one of the columns though needs the lastInsertID to append another column.  We are building file names off of record IDs.  Instead of doing a 2nd `update` to the newly inserted record, is it possible to get the value of the ID column and append to it in the same mysql insert?

Using PHP, currently I am doing:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (id,idName) values (null,?)" ;
list($lastID,$inError,$inResult) = dbInsert($query,array("")) ;

Then:
$appString = $lastID . "-S1001.pdf" ;
$query = "UPDATE table SET idName=? WHERE id=?" ;
list($upCount,$upError) = dbUpdate($query,array($appString,$lastID)) ;
```

But is there a way to merge the INSERT and UPDATE into a single statment?

```
$apString = "-S1001.pdf" ;
$query = "INSERT INTO table (id,idName) values (null,id.$appString)" ;
list($lastID,$inError,$inResult) = dbInsert($query,array()) ;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP/MySQL insert row then get 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id)

Comment: No, all of those solutions are just as I am currently doing it - pretty much INSERT, then get lastID, then do what ever.  Can I get lastInsertID of the record being inserted to be used in the same insert?

Comment: The id is already part of your table so why store it again?  Anytime you do a query its a simple matter of using concat(id, '-', appString) as filename

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a `trigger` that will do your update whenever you insert a row into the table?
This way, you don't need to manually do the second query. Just the insert.